# How to configure an external wireless network card in windows 7

Tags: wireless-networking, network-adapter, packet-injection

I have a external wireless card of D-Link, which I generally use in Linux Mint. But I wanna use it in windows too. After spending a lot of time googling, i realized that configuring it in windows (just like the `ifconfig` and `iwconfig` commands in linux would let you do) is not that straightforward in windows 7.

I recently wrote a packet capturer/analyzer/injector tool n when I started injecting packets on that interface, n sniffed using wireshark (on the same iface of course), nothing was captured. Tried another injector software (Colasoft), but still nothing. Just couldn't get it to work..I think it isn't in operational mode ("up") or something.. Anybody done this before? Any suggestions on how to configure it are welcome.

Machine is Windows 7 32bit.

Comment: and yes, my network card DOES support injection, and everything works fine with the internal WiFi network adapter.

Comment: Does the external nic connect to your LAN normally? If you disable the internal nic, are you still able to connect or is all traffic only running over the internal nic?

Comment: When I boot up in linux, I'm able to do everything imaginable thing, wid my NIC. and I never tried to disable my internal NIC.

Comment: If you run ipconfig /all from the cmd prompt, does the external adapter show up and is it connected? Or, if you go into control panle-> network and internet -> network connections, do you see the external nic as enabled?

Comment: Yes it shows up in ipconfig. But I wanna change the settings, not only view it.

Comment: When I go to network connections and connect it to my Wifi network, then I'm able to inject packets, otherwise not. How to put it in the operational mode without having windows do it for me automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you just want to be able to enable and disable by the command line?

If so, per the directions [here](http://itcookbook.net/blog/enabling-and-disabling-nics-commandline-windows)

You need to get a list of NICs and their index numbers with the command:

```
wmic nic get name, index
```

The disable command is (for example, for nic 7):

```
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call disable
```

The enable command is:

```
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call enable
```